# XML Digital Signature Certificate

Tags: digital-signature, xml-signature

I would Like to know which type of certificate do I need to get from a Certification Authority to Sign an XML Document (XML-DSIG) in .NET ? shold i get an SSL certificate?

We have a xml electronic invoice that we need to sign using a Digital Certificate.

Any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What certificate do I buy to sign XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674894/what-certificate-do-i-buy-to-sign-xml)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not SSL. I guess [Document Signing offer by GlobalSign](http://www.globalsign.com/authentication-secure-email/enterprise-pki/secure-microsoft-office.html) will work for "regular" XML as well. Also, it can be that local authorities (either CA or those organizations that require or accept signed documents) issue some special certificates for your task.